# C#, Regex, string of a specific length and pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string, md5

I've got a problem with checking whether the string is md5 or not. I know that it should contain "0123456789ABCDEF" and its length equals to 32. I know that regex is a good way to check it, but I have no idea to use it. I tried searching on msdn but nothing cleared my mind. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the regex `[0-9a-f]{32}`:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(string, @"[0-9a-f]{32}"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    //String is MD5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have seen posts about regex and so on, but I had no idea how to use it! Thanks! :)